# Is there anyway to recover a missing git commit?

Tags: git, git-commit

I've been working with a detached head for longer than I should have granted. I've been lazy and put off merging back into the branch I was originally working in and finally decided that it was high time I do what I ought to do.

So I assumed that the best way was to follow the same procedure as I always do. First I fetched and then pulled down the newest changes to that branch, fixed merge conflicts and then I merged the branch I was going to merge with into the the commit I had first. (in hindsight, I'm not even sure what I did here after thinking it through more thoroughly). Then I wrote down the commit id for the commit I had recently made with all my current work in and then checked out the branch I was going to merge that into........... That's when my stomach hit my feet. The commit was gone. I tried searching for the id in SourceTree and got nothing... I can't find my work anywhere.

Have I blown away all this work or is there some way to get it back?.. I was under the impression that once Git made a commit, it was always there, like a save button.

Comment: check if your changes are still there?

Comment: @leoOrion They are not

Comment: you checked into the branch you were gonna merge into but not yet merged rite? Check out to your previous branch and see if tis there?

Comment: @leoOrion I think I've not expressed the issue clearly. I was not working in a branch. A while ago, I had merged in a change that broke my code. So while others were fixing that, I checked out the commit right before that merge and have just been lazy to get back into the branch. I tried to merge the commit into a branch. I'm working with SourceTree as a GUI for git and it shows no commit with the id that I had made just about 15 minutes ago. The last commit it shows was two days ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all changes that have been committed as some point, `git` has a big built in safety net : the reflog.

Run :

```
git reflog
```

You should see the commit(s) you are looking for there.

Comment: I'm looking at this now. Is there a way to sort or to know how its sorting commits? I don't see the id I wrote down right off or the commit message.

Comment: I mean if I saw the id existing prior to this, is there anyway the id would just "disappear"?

Comment: I have been (foolishly) relying on SourceTree for navigation. I just tried a simple "git checkout <commit id>" into the bash and I think I'm saved! I keep being reminded why I prefer the bash. SourceTree is fine for basic stuff but I'm always driven back to the bash.